# Why is my ```document.querySelector``` unable to select the button element?

Tags: javascript

I'm unable to select the button element with `document.querySelector`. Essentially I'm just trying to apply a class to the button element with JS logic. But I can't select the element.

I have tried using other select methods like `document.getElementById` and it allowed me to select the button element. But I'm just confused as to why querySelector does not work.

HTML:

```html
<button class="units__fahrenheit units__fahrenheit--active">&#176;F</button>
<!-- <span class="units__divider">|</span> -->
<button class="units__celcius">&#176;C</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.units__fahrenheit {
  background: transparent;
}
.units__fahrenheit--active {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

.units__celcius {
  background: transparent;
}
.units__celcius--active {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```js
const $fahUnit = document.querySelector(".units__fahrenheight");
const $celUnit = document.querySelector(".units__celcius");

export const bindUnitEvents = _ => { 
  $fahUnit.addEventListener("click", _ => { 
    $fahUnit.classList.add("units__fahrenheight--active");
    $celUnit.classList.remove("units__celcius--active");
  });
  $celUnit.addEventListener("click", _ => { 
    $fahUnit.classList.remove("units__fahrenheight--active");
    $celUnit.classList.add("units__celcius--active");
  });
}
```

I expect the button element to be selected with `document.querySelector` method but it does not seem to work.

It gave me an error of:

```
units.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Comment: spelling? `.units__fahrenheight` vs `units__fahrenheit`

Comment: Might as well spell `Celsius` correctly as well.

Comment: Maybe you did call bindUnitEvents externally?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the script file is loaded before HTML is rendered. Try moving script file import at the end of body tag, it will all work. Plus the spellings.

Answer (score 0):

As some others have mentioned in the comments you have several misspellings that are causing issues when looking for elements on the DOM. (fahrenheight vs fahrenheit)

HTML:

```
<button class="units__fahrenheit units__fahrenheit--active">&#176;F</button>
<!-- <span class="units__divider">|</span> -->
<button class="units__celcius">&#176;C</button>
```

CSS:

```
.units__fahrenheit {
  background: transparent;
}
.units__fahrenheit--active {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

.units__celcius {
  background: transparent;
}
.units__celcius--active {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Also i removed the export from your `bindUnitEvents` function and executed it at the end of the script (e.g bindUnitEvents())

JS:

```
const $fahUnit = document.querySelector(".units__fahrenheit");
console.log($fahUnit)
const $celUnit = document.querySelector(".units__celcius");

const bindUnitEvents = _ => { 
  $fahUnit.addEventListener("click", _ => { 
    $fahUnit.classList.add("units__fahrenheit--active");
    $celUnit.classList.remove("units__celcius--active");
  });
  $celUnit.addEventListener("click", _ => { 
    $fahUnit.classList.remove("units__fahrenheit--active");
    $celUnit.classList.add("units__celcius--active");
  });
}

bindUnitEvents()
```

After doing this, the solution works for me! Hope this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/b956pL8s/1/